How do I ensure that the stresses are accounted for at the center of the wheel as well?
So I'm trying to run a centrifugal stress analysis on a flywheel in SolidWorks, but I'm unsure of how I should fix the model in a way where von Mises stresses are accounted for even at the center of the wheel. Most tutorials I've seen on YouTube recommend fixing the rod, but according to a flywheel's stress equation, the maximum stress occurs at the center of the wheel. As seen in the image, the simulation doesn't take into account the central stresses if I fix the rod.
In the model, the rod and the hub are part of the same piece. I'll add a hole at the top for a motor spindle and a bearing at the bottom, but first I'm trying to make sure the flywheel doesn't fail at high speeds.



You could try to fix circumferential displacements at the cylindrical surface of the rod and then just fix axial displacement at one or both of the rod ends. This way, all nodes are able to freely move in radial direction (except the ones on the axis of course). (You may need to ad cylindrical coordinate system to be able to fix circumferential displacements.)

Is there a way to better show this using Ansys?

In Mechanical, you would need to add cylindrical coordinate system with proper orientation. After that, when you define displacement boundary condition, you can choose this new coordinate system. In old MAPDL, you would also need to create properly oriented cylindrical system, but in the next step you just use it for rotating local nodal systems (command NROT) of selected nodes.
